# react native axios/fetch and UI run on same thread

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Does in react native axios/fetch and UI run on same thread. If I have a heavy upload when app comes to foreground will that impact UI interactions??
My app freezes whenever it comes in foreground. User can scroll but cannot tap on any button or navigate?
Know issue on Redmi Devices.

Comment: can you share your code ?  do you have any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

the axios/fetch are running on the Javascript thread